# Different restartPolicy for initContainers and main containers

Tags: kubernetes, cron, openshift

How to restart an init Container but not the app/main container?

Hey there, I built a CronJob using OC 3.11 (version fix by company). The job's **backoffLimit** is set to **0**. The pod's **restartPolicy** is set to **Never**.

The idea of the CronJob is to perform a healthcheck using cURL, wheras the init container is just preparing some stuff. That implies:

- The failing of the init container **does not** indicate that the healthcheck failed.
- The failing of the app/main container **does** indicate that the healthcheck failed.

To change the **restartPolicy** to **OnFailure** is not an option, because:

- The pod's restart policy applies to all containers.
- In case the app/main container fails, I need a failed **pod** for alerting/monitoing reasons.

To change the job's backoffLimit is not an option, because:

- In case the app/main container fails, I need a failed **job** for alerting/monitoing reasons.

In short, I search for a way to restart the init container as long/many retries as it takes without failing the pod or job, but the pod and job has to fail immediately as the app/main container fails.

Thank you.